# Where I can find a good Architecture Diagram of Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Right now I am evaluating multiple tools in order to implement Full Text Search.
I was able to easily find an Architecture Diagram that explains Lucene and same goes for SolR but even searching through google images, I cannot find a decent diagram that explain the structure of Elastic Search and its relationship with Lucene components.
Can you point me to a right resource that highlight through an architecture diagram the structure of Elastic Search?